# On eclipse I can't seem to run a JUnit test, the main error it says is that it find the testing.squareUnit path

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

In testing.testOne, "testing" is the package and "testOne" is the class

This is the error:

[image: 1]

This is the file explorer:

[image: 2]

Comment: i think you forgot to include error message, please update question to include error message

Comment: Please show the launch configuration.

Comment: Strange I did add the error message, I put two pics, the file explorer and the error message.